# parent and sub pages are not working properly in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a main page in wordpress http://www.hcla.edu.au/dates-and-fees/ and a sub-page http://www.hcla.edu.au/dates-and-fees/payment-methods/

Whenever I click on the "payment methods" page, it shows the "Dates and Fees" Page.

Please share your suggestions about why would the parent and subpage feature is failing to work properly?

Comment: It doesn't show the dates and fees page. It shows the payments methods page, which is a **child** of the dates and fees page. Add some unique content to the payment methods page and you'll only see it on the payment methods page.

Comment: I think problem with your breadcrumb, to verify the page put the_title() to see the page title.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I tried to add unique content like you say but it doesn't work. It should work without content anyway. http://imgur.com/a/d79cd